# Regex not matching, need help figuring out why

Tags: regex

The regex is:

```
<td class="description">(?<lineItem>[\w/ -]+)<\/td>\s+<td class="descriptionFormat">(?:[\w\$%\.,()\/ ]*)</td>\s+<td class="amount">[ ]*(?<lineValue>-?\$(?:\d{1,3},?)+\.\d{2})</td>
```

Ignore case, multi line, and single line are enabled.

An example of a statement that matches is:

```
<td class="description">Fuel Cost Adjustment</td>
<td class="descriptionFormat">18,640 KWH at -$0.00044</td>
<td class="amount">$-1.36</td>
```

But this one does not match:

```
<td class="description">Fuel Cost Adjustment</td>
<td class="descriptionFormat">18,640 KWH at -$0.00044 (25/30 Days)</td>
<td class="amount">$-6.84</td>
```

I'd really appreciate if anyone could tell me what's wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: You have some unescaped `</td>` in your regex instead of `<\/td>` is that a typo ?

Comment: I am not sure as I inherited this code. It is in production and doesn't break often so I'm going to assume it is safe? I'll play with that and see if it helps though!

Comment: The `/` in the `[\w/ -]` is not escaped too. It should be `[\w\/ -]`. https://regex101.com/r/1gFUga/1/

Comment: But the original regex is weird: `\s+` became `[ ]*` like he feel like the `*` will do a better job but get rid of the `\s`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(<td class="description">)(?<lineItem>[\w/ -]+)<\/td>\s*<td class="descriptionFormat">(?:[\w\$%\-\.,\(\)\/ ]*)\s*</td>\s*<td class="amount">\s*(?<lineValue>-?\$(-|)(?:\d{1,3},?)+\.\d{2})</td>
```

should match, but you might consider updating this a bit since html parsing with regex is rather tricky; unless you´re 100% percent sure the inputdata wont change in any way

Comment: Thank you so much. Initial tests seem to pass! The input data, if in HTML, should not change. It has been consistent for a year or so now. I know regex and HTML are a horrible choice but...I was given a lemon!